# "Contest" vs. "competition"

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns

I've read plenty of discussions, and I wanted to know whether the following statements are true or false:

- *contest* is more casual than *competition*
- a *competition* relies more on intelligence while a *contest* is associated to brute strength (well, I have my doubts about this one)
- a *contest* always involves a prize while *competition* usually doesn't
- a *contest* refers to a single event while a *competition* can last a whole season

In my case, it's a programming contest (which sounds better than programming competition I think), it's (supposed to be) fun, it lasts several months and involves a prize. Should I keep *contest*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the words are more synonomous and interchangable than you've described in your question.  Here are some of my reservations:

- *Contest* isn't always associated with brute strength (the term *beauty contest* comes to mind)
- Either a contest or a competition could have a prize (in Olympics gymnastics, for example, there is the *all-around competition*).
- *Competition* seems no less applicable to a one-time event than the word *contest* (observe how this reporter talks about the [outdoor cooking competition](http://www.boston.com/yourtown/news/dorchester/2012/08/dorchester_chefs_claim_top_pri.html)).

With all that said, however, I still agree with your final choice: I'd probably vote for *programming contest* over *programming competition*; that wording seems to emphasize that the event is intended to be more *fun*, and less *cutthroat*.

One other word you might consider is *challenge*: The 2012 Programming Challenge.

Answer (score 9):

*Contest* refers to conflicts more generally. It's first meaning is the legal one, where different parties contest something in court (it comes from the Latin for calling a witness), and can refer to military conflict, elections etc.

*Compete* refers to a case where people try to do better than each other at something (business would be another example where we talk of *competition* and *competitors*).

While this may mean the former seems the more aggressive, it's also more applicable to cases where what one is contesting isn't ones competitors, but other conditions. A case where everyone who attained a particular result was considered to have won would be a contest (they're struggling against whatever the challenge is, and may or may not achieve the goal) but not a competition (another participant doing well does not make their winning any harder, so they aren't competing).

For this reason, while they're close synonyms in many cases, *contest* has a stronger nuance of reflecting the challenge itself, and *competition* of doing better than other participants.

Answer (score 2):

Contest suggests playing a game for the game's sake just to see who would win, or maybe playing for candy. But  competition suggests playing the game in order to get some big reward, where the reward and the achievement is the only thing that is important, and there may be no pleasure in the game.

Answer (score 0):

As a summary it could be said that:

Contest -> No sport. [Math Contest](https://w3dir.com/133k)

Competition -> Sport. [Athletic Competition](https://w3dir.com/133l)

Comment: Actually, Alex, one may have an athletic contest and a math competition.

Comment: @J.Taylor not at the same time I hope? That'd be a really challenge.

Comment: @JJJ Well, now that you mention it, I have been in situations, that combined arithmetic and physical skill, that placed me  against others. The whole could be either competition or contest.

Comment: @J.Taylor a mathletic comptest ;)